# Unexpected return value of a function

Tags: c

In the user defined `func` i have assinged the value 10 into `k`. the function is returning the value of `sum`. Why is the function returning the value of `sum` and not the value of `k`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int func(int i, int j){
    int sum = 0;
    sum = i + j;
    int k = 10;

}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d%d", &i, &j);
    printf("%d", func(i, j));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [C11 6.9.1p12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12) applies here: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Just for comparison: C++ is even stricter, already UB even if return value is unused...

Answer (score 3):

Your function is declared as returning an `int`, but it doesn't have any `return` statement! Therefore it is undefined behavior to access the return value of such function. It could cause any random value to be read, or even do worse. The fact that the value you get is the same as `sum` is only a coincidence.

The correct way to achieve what you want would be to add `return k;` at the end of the function body.

Comment: Side note: The only function allowed not to return a value is `main`.

Comment: @Aconcagua well, just because return 0 is implicit in main, so technically it always returns a value.

Comment: It is not undefined behavior for a function with a non-void return type not to return a value. It is undefined behavior to **use** the return value of a function if it does not return a value, per C 2018 6.9.1 12: “Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.”

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you want to know the reason why the function doesn't return the value of the last evaluated statement and returns something else randomly: the C runtime calling convention uses a specific register for return values (usually `eax`). The `return` statement specifically loads the desired value into this register, whereas in the absence of it the register contains the last value moved into it (mainly garbage from the last executed statements), which could be any previous statement, not necessary the last one. That's why the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Also, for this particular example, `int k = 10;` doesn't involve any registers. It only has to move the immediate value `10` into a stack location.

Comment: It depends on the compiler if `k` will end up in a register, on stack, or will be optimized away completely.

Answer (score 0):

compiling the posted code results in:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled.c"  
untitled.c: In function ‘func’:
untitled.c:6:9: warning: unused variable ‘k’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int k = 10;
     ^

untitled.c:4:9: warning: variable ‘sum’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int sum = 0;
     ^~~

untitled.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

However, the main problem with the OPs code is the lack of the statement:

```
return sum;
```

just before the last closing brace '}' of the `func()` function